# Do Salmon Run matches change difficulty when players drop?

Tags: splatoon-2

I was recently doing a Salmon Run where a player disconnected early on during the match. Shortly after, my team was overrun, which I didn't find too surprising. What I did find surprising though was seeing the Grizzco give me a pay-cut because of the early loss, even when we were seemingly fighting with a fairly significant disadvantage.

When someone drops from a Salmon Run, does the game adjust the difficulty, and is it instant or after the next wave starts? Or does losing a team member mean you've got a handicap for the rest of this match?

Comment: I seem to remember our quota dropping as soon as a player dropped connection, but I'm not sure if the difficulty is affected too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the difficulty is adjusted instantly. Specifically, the egg quotas of the current and future waves are significantly reduced as soon as a player drops out. Enemy spawns also decrease, but this is less noticeable.

Salmon Run is intended to be played locally with 2-4 players, so there is appropriate difficulty scaling built in. Ordinarily it can't be played with 1 player, although this does apparently happen to some people online if their lobby times out, so I'm not sure what it would be like in that case.

Note however that having less than 4 players in online Salmon Run means that at least one of the intended weapons will be missing from the field. This can put you at a disadvantage against certain enemy types.